# Composer in Symfony2 creates the same assets twice (jquery, jqueryui)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, symfony, composer-php

I added jquery and jqueryui to composer.json:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "components/jquery": "1.11.*@dev",
    "components/jqueryui": "1.10.4"
}
```

and composer is downloading both libraries and puts them into vendor/components but also into components/, so I've got two copies of these libs. How can I rid off components/ directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the component's output-directory with the `component-dir` directive in your `composer.json's`config` section.

**example:**

```
{
    "require": {
        "components/jquery": "~1.10"
    },
    "config": {
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    }
}
```

It defaults to `components`.

Just set it to `/tmp` to *"disable"* dumping to the second directoy.

**Edit:** Sadly composer refuses to accept setting the target to `/dev/null`.

Read more about the configuration in the [component-installer documentation](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer#installation-directory).

Comment: Actually it didn't work; composer threw an exception that /dev/null exists but it's not a directory, but I set it up to /tmp and works fine, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I fixed the answer. Please accept the answer so we have this issue marked as *solved*.