# What is the best way to include jQuery for symfony project using composer and assets

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, composer-php

I have jQuery installed with composer.

Now jQuery is in `vendor/components/jquery` directory.

I've tried to include that in `/app/config/config.yml`

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
    assets:
        jquery: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

If I run the command:

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

I get

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                                                              
  The source file "/home/user/project/app/current/app/../web/vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js" does not exist.
```

Cause assetic is still looking in the `/web/` directory which is wrong. How can I change it so it will look in the `/vendor/` directory? Also I don't want to put the jquery files in the public bundle folder cause that would brake all the sense of getting the right versions of vendor libraries via composer.

Comment: It's probably worth using the google cdn for jquery as most users will have already cached it: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: @user1 thank you. But no, imagine what happens if google is offline, my webApp would then also be broken just because of that ...

Comment: it's pretty unlikely

Comment: The major CDNs are extremely reliable. In fact, they've had zero downtime in the last 3 months: https://www.cdnperf.com/#jsdelivr,cdnjs,google,yandex,microsoft,jquery,bootstrapcdn/https/90.

Comment: Ok ok, guys, that was just a joke. I don't want to include it over google. Imagine if the App should run only inside a company and can not connect to the outside world.

Comment: I guess you can configure where Composer should install the components? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998144/composer-in-symfony2-creates-the-same-assets-twice-jquery-jqueryui

Comment: Thank you @dlondero, I've tried that but nothing changed. Removed cache,  installed composer, assets and dumped assets multiple times, but no jquery in `/web/` dir

Comment: I suggest you to read [this answer about the different ways to include jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41324944/1941316).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of installing jquery in the vendor directory in Symfony, as it's not a PHP library. Composer and `vendor` directory should only be used for PHP dependencies. 
You should separates the frontend part from the backend part.
All the js, css and other assets should go somewhere else.

Therefore you have 2 options:

1. If you want to have separate resources per bundle, then put your resources you use for the frontend in the public directory of your bundle: for example put your `jquery.min.js` in the `Resources/public/js` folder of your bundle.

Then run the command `php app/console assets:install`. this will copy your js files to the `web/bundles/yourbundle/js/` directory.

Finally use `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('yourbundle/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>` in your twig file to add jquery.

2. If you have common resources for all your bundles, put your resources directly in the `web` folder, for example: `web/js`, `web/css`, `web/img`...
   And then use `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>` in your twig template.

Comment: +1 and thank you @Youring_G! I didn't know about "Composer and vendor directory should only be used for PHP dependencies." To separate front- and backend makes sense. I still like the idea that it could be possible to update those files via `composer`

Answer (score 1):

While following the links from comments and retrying other answers it was pretty easy. Everything missing was

```
composer require robloach/component-installer
```

[more information about robloach/component-installer](https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer#installation-directory)

Then add this line manually to `composer.json`

```
"config": {
    #...
    "component-dir": "web/assets",
    #...
},
```

Assumed that you already have

```
composer require components/jquery
```

You might have to rerun the command

```
composer install
```

Now it will create a directory `/web/assets/jquery` with all the files which will be easy to include.

Comment: **Component Installer has been deprecated**

Comment: @Jonathan indeed true that robloach/component-installer is deprecated, however there seems to be no good alternative.  I've tried a few and have decided the above, despite being deprecated, is the best approach.

Comment: Never, simply **never** rely on deprecated, outdated, untested or unstable software.